# Limit on amount of solution configurations in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio

Do you guys know of any limit on the amount of configurations that can be created for a solution in VS 2010? I'm in a project where we need 4 configurations for our solution. I was able to create the first 3, but when I tried to create the 4th one, the config manager dialog box just closes and the configuration is not created. I've tried this on 3 different machines.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a limit, but I do know that if there is, it's a *lot* higher than the three you have!  I've seen a solution with about 7 before, and heard of solutions with many more.